# Need with perfect infinitive

Tags: grammar, semi-modals

I know the difference between

1) I needn’t have done it (but I did it) – I didn’t need to do it (and I didn't do it.)

But do these make sense? I have come across them being uttered or written by native speakers

2) I need to have done it. – I needed to do it. (What's the semantic difference?)

3) Need you have done it? – Did you need to do it? (What's the semantic difference?)

Answer (score 1):

In your 2) *I need to have done it* is a present-tense use of *need* and is only meaningful with a future reference, such as *I need to have done it by Friday, because I'm leaving town on Saturday*. *I needed to do it* is a past-tense use of *need* and refers to a past necessity, such as *I needed to do it right away, because I was to meet the client that afternoon.

The two sentences in your 3) mean the same thing. Note that the first sentence employs *need* as a modal, taking the bare infinitive (without *to*). This is an old use which in effect treats the present form as immutable, like *must*:  the *have done* construction is not a true perfect but a perfect employed as a modal past marker. *Need have VERBed* has been steadily declining since about 1900, and is nearly defunct now.

Comment: Can the 3 mean that I am pretty sure that my addressee didn't  need to do it and I am king of rebuking him?

Comment: @user1425 It *may* mean that, and usually does; but it may be a simple question. That will depend on context.

Comment: I have found "need to have done" referring to the past as it seems "And it is scarce credible what inexpressible labor everything was done with , especially the bringing piles out of the woods , and driving them into the ground ; for I made them much bigger than I need to have done"

Answer (score 0):

In your #2, it likely would be read as past perfect "have done it".  Since, as StoneyB pointed out, this is only meaningful with a future reference, the example as you gave it is nonsensical. Either you have done it or you haven't; you cannot change the past, so you can't "need" to change it. The best you can do is to wish you had, by saying "I should have done it."